# Best way to have variable in form action like <input type text="">?

Tags: php, forms, action

Can have form action something like this:

```
   <form method=post action="$myvariable">
    <input type=text value="$myvariable">
```

How to do this?
No matter way, javascript also can be used to get $myvariable (form action).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but when you use PHP within HTML, it has to be enclosed in the PHP tags, so you would do something like this:

```
<form method=post action="<?php echo $myvariable; ?>">
    <input type=text value="<?php echo $myvariable; ?>">
```

Comment: @any Caissy: Yes, I need it for my form action and need to insert this action in <input type=text name=action value="$myvariable">

Comment: I've updated the code, it should do what you want now.

Comment: Is there any example of forms like this, where I can type a different action URL in same form - to see how it is written?

Comment: @any Caissy: This your is code of two same lines, it is when I define "$myvariable", but I can't define variable, just type in <input type=text > it is also when I want to have like Name: / Email: in $variable, but I don't want that - I need ACTION to have in variable, not normal <input type=text name=email value=<? echo $myvariable; ?>> etc. ACTION, - not name or email value, but <form action="<? $myvariable; >>.

Comment: I tried <form action="<? $myvariable; >> but is not worked. Not worked to me with combination of <input type=text name=action value="<? $myvariable; >>

Comment: @ Dany Caissy Yes, thanks... That already I tried and not work for me, maybe with javascript will work but I have no idea how?

Comment: @user4559466 *I tried and not work for me* What problem did you encounter?

Comment: @A.L It not works at all, there is no any value for $myvariable in <form action="">